# Use checkboxes in MVC view and pass checked state back to controller for processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an IList of objects that I pass using a ViewModel to my view.

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Reminder()
    {
        using(var db = new SalonContext())
        {
            var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
            var homeSalon = GetHomeSalonId();
            var myAppointments = db.Appointments.Include(c => c.Customer).Include(c => c.Treatment).Include(c => c.Stylist).Include(c => c.Salon).Where(c => c.SalonId == homeSalon).ToList();
            var tomorrowsAppointments = myAppointments.Where(a => a.Start.Date == tomorrow).Select(rem => new FutureAppointment
                {
                    AppointmentId = rem.AppointmentId,
                    Name = rem.Customer.Title + " " +rem.Customer.FirstName + " " + rem.Customer.Surname,
                    AppointmentTime = rem.Start,
                    Salon = rem.Salon.Name,
                    Stylist = rem.Stylist.FirstName,
                    Treatment = rem.Treatment.Name,
                    Email = rem.Customer.EMail,
                    SendReminder = true
                }).ToList();

            return View(tomorrowsAppointments);
        }
    }
```

The view renders the list with the check boxes using this code:

```
@model IList<MySalonOrganiser.Models.FutureAppointment>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Email Reminders";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("Reminder", "Appointment", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Send Reminder
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Appointment Time
            </th>
            <th>
                Salon
            </th>
            <th>
                Treatment
            </th>
            <th>
                Stylist
            </th>
            <th>
                EMail
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @for (var i =0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].SendReminder)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].AppointmentTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Salon)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Treatment)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Stylist)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Email)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
     <div>
        <input type="Submit" value="Send Reminders" />
    </div>

}
```

When I post the view back to the controller, I see the list's items of type FutureAppointment in the returned model, but everything except the checkbox state is null.

Can anyone help me with why and how to fix this so I see all the model data?

Jason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your form only contains input fields for the checkboxes. The DisplayFor helper will only create a text or label or whatever displaying the value of the other fields. You can fix this by adding hidden inputs for them:

```
@for (var i =0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].SendReminder)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].AppointmentTime)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].AppointmentTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Salon)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Salon)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Treatment)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Treatment)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Stylist)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Stylist)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Email)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Email)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Under each of the `DisplayFor` calls, add a `@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x[i].Property)` call to add a hidden field containing the same value.

The hidden field values will then get posted by the form and bound to your model when the data hits your controller.

The `DisplayFor` will only add a label to the output (*unless overridden for the model with a display template*), label values do not get posted by a form.

Answer (score 1):

You are not posting back the values. `Html.DisplayFor` does not generate input tags, and only inputs inside a form are posted back to server. You will have to use `Html.TexBoxFor` or `Html.HiddenFor` methods for those properties.